# How to use ngSubmit via ionic-framework (angular2)

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, ionic2

I have a ion-searchbar declared in my hello-ionic.html,

when I press enter, I want to submit the data back to hello-ionic.js and call toSearch function

May I know how do i initialize this?

**Html**

```
<ion-searchbar (ionInput)="onInput($event)"></ion-searchbar>
```

**JS**

```
onInput(event)
{
    console.log("ASD");
}
```

---

I tried this on a clean ionic file and it works, I have cleaned my own file but it still doesn't work. May I know what modules / dependencies version it requires?

---

*SOLVED*

USE (input) instead of (ionInput) on ionic v1